# The polyglot challenge!

Tags: code-challenge, polyglot

A polyglot is a program which can be run by several different language's interpreters/compilers without failing.

For example, [the stackoverflow 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/forty-two) contains a polyglot which runs in Python, Perl, Ruby, C, brainfuck and befunge, each time printing 404 to stdout.

[image: 404]

Now, my challenge is to create a polyglot which, when run as a certain language, will print:

> Just Another #{Name Of Language} Hacker,

So, if you say that your program can be run as both JavaScript and ><>, when run in a JavaScript environment it should print

```
Just Another JavaScript Hacker,
```

and when run by a ><> interpreter,

```
Just Another ><> Hacker,
```

In your answers, you should list the number of languages which accept it as a valid program and produce correct output, as well as a list of those languages.

The program which runs under the most languages wins!

Comment: @flawr it's an exact duplicate of the second dupe target though. If this was considered sufficiently different (which I don't think it is), I'd say the older challenge should be reopened.