# "I know that language - that's Java. No? It's Perl?"

Tags: code-challenge, polyglot

### Introduction

A known fact is that Jon Skeet [can code Perl and make it look like Java](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9156/307207). In this challenge you will try to do something similar.

### Challenge

Write a piece of code of any length that can be executed **without any errors/exceptions** in two different languages. Your program can take inputs, give outputs, whatever it wants.

The code has to be executed with interpreters/compilers of your choice one after another (with *basic* settings, means you are not allowed to adjust the compiler/interpreter settings).

*Note that the source code and any used sources (files, libs and so on) are **not** allowed to change during the execution of the script with the compilers/interpreters.*

### But which languages are "different"?

Two languages are different from each other if they are not the same language without looking at the version. **Example:** *Python 3.5* is not different to *Python 2.7*.

### Scoring

The final score consists out of several aspects:

- **charScore**: Take your code and then (max charScore is 95)...

  1. Look at every function and delete all arguments (in *echo "Hello"* "Hello" counts as an argument). So now only keywords and functions count. **Example:** *System.out.println(1+1);* becomes *System.out.println();*
  2. Make all strings to empty strings *and all regex and literals* empty. **Example:** *"khffshiufahk"* becomes *""* and all regex (without string) gets deleted.
  3. Delete all comments. **Example:** *//Jon Skeet would also do this* becomes *[nothing]*
     _Definition of "comment": _ Anything that doesn't change the execution of the program (So you could simply leave them out and nothing would change).
  4. Delete all characters that are not unicode 32-126. **Example:** *print(2²)* becomes *print(2)*
  5. Count only the *occurrences* of the letters. **Example:** *hiiiiiii-thhheeeree* has the same score as *hi-there* (means score of 8)

  Here is a StackSnippet to do step 3 and 4 for you (report me if there is a bug):

  ```js
  function calcScore() {
   var onlyValidChars = "";
   var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
   for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if (code[i].charCodeAt(0)>=32 && code[i].charCodeAt(0)<=126) { //step 3
       if (onlyValidChars.indexOf(code[i]) === -1) { //step 4
         onlyValidChars += code[i];
           }
         }
   }
    return onlyValidChars.length;
  }
  function showCalcScore() {
   alert("Your charScore: "+calcScore());
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <body>
      <textarea placeholder="Insert your code here." id="code"></textarea>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="showCalcScore();">calculate score</button>
    </body>
  ```
- **+20** if your code is still executable in both languages now (after the *charScore-changes*)
- **+50** if running the code with the different interpreters does different things (eg order change, prints other things etc)
- **+15** if your languages are Perl and Java

The answer with the highest score wins.

**EDIT:** I don't think that [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4481) is a duplicate (but very releated) because it has no "different language" limits and no score. On the other hand, I didn't know about so-called "polyglot"-code so maybe  I am wrong.

Comment: This is my first question on this site. If anything is unclear feel free to ask or edit. (I'm not sure if everything is clear in this challenge.)

Comment: What tags should I use for this question?

Comment: @Mego It it very releated but not the same I think.

Comment: The [tag:polyglot] tag applies, and I would also recommend looking over existing polyglot challenges if you haven't already done so.

Comment: The scoring is different.

Comment: You should make rule #1 under charScore include regex literals (and perhaps other kinds of literals). Otherwise a single regex literal that includes every single character is a valid Ruby+Perl submission.

Comment: @Doorknob You are probably right. That doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: How could I put that into regex?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of "comments"?

Comment: Also, Pyth and Python 3 are *very* different.  One is specifically designed for golfing, and the other isn't.  Pyth was originally derived from python, but now is its own language.

Comment: @Doorknob Edited the question.

Comment: @RikerW Yeah, that was just an example. I know that the filtering is not the best. First, I wanted to have [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type) but that would have made everything very complicated.

Comment: @Doorknob The question - charScore - 1 now includes regex and literals. But there is another problem: You could probably also make a request to http://abc.de/fegh... :(

Comment: @palsch just limit it to different versions of the same language.  That generally works fine.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP + [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), 165

Scoring calculation: 95 + 20 + 50.

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

In PHP, this outputs the string verbatim (since there is no `<?` to signal for the preprocessor functionality).

In [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), this is an infinite loop.

The charScore changes do not affect the program, as it consists of all 95 printable ASCII characters once, so it is eligible for the +20 bonus.

Comment: Pig does not seem to fulfill the requirements of a valid programming language.

Comment: @PhiNotPi This has been rectified (s/Pig/Lenguage/).

Comment: I guess it's a lucky coincidence that lenguage program #95 is an infinite loop.

Comment: @PhiNotPi Not really. Anything that doesn't output that string would have worked anyway.